# How to show an advice message if a cell is blank in google sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

i hope you can help me.
I have this code, and i want to display an alert if the cell is blank, and also, if it is dont paste the information on my DB.

```js
function Guardar() {
    var hojaActiva = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var registro = hojaActiva.getSheetByName("Macro de Solicitud");
    var bd = hojaActiva.getSheetByName("Respuestas Macro de Solicitud");
    var valores = [
        [
            registro.getRange("c16").getValue(),
            registro.getRange("j13").getValue(),
            registro.getRange("f14").getValue(),
            registro.getRange("c4").getValue(),
            registro.getRange("c6").getValue(),
            registro.getRange("c8").getValue(),
            registro.getRange("c10").getValue(),
            registro.getRange("c12").getValue(),
            registro.getRange("c14").getValue(),
            registro.getRange("f4").getValue(),
            registro.getRange("f6").getValue(),
            registro.getRange("f8").getValue(),
            registro.getRange("f10").getValue(),
            registro.getRange("f12").getValue(),
            registro.getRange("f16").getValue()
        ]
    ];
    bd.getRange(bd.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 15).setValues(valores);
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### Alert if range is blank

```
function lfunko() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const rgl = sh.getRangeList(["c16","j13","f14","c4","c6","c8","c10","c12","c14","f4","f6","f8","f10","f12"]);
  rgl.getRanges().forEach(r => {if(r.isBlank()){ui.alert(`${r.getA1Notation()} is blank`)}});
}
```

Comment: Thank you mate, was really helpful, you know how can i stop the function "guardar" if there is a cell in blank? I mean the code you post has to be in the same function, to execute all at the same time

Answer (score 0):

In your sheet names 'Macro de Solicitud' add a formula in a cell that count the number of values in C16,J13,F14,etc. and compare with the number of cells. By checking the result you will find if one at least cell is blank before pasting the informations in your data base..

Comment: Yeah, that could work, but this sheet is going to be worked by many people, and i want this to be the easiest for everyody